# How to display the user name that created the profile (the owner or author of the profile)?

Tags: 8, theming, users

I have a site with Drupal 8 and I want to customize the templates of my pages.

I use the module:

- "Profile" https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/profile

Here is my template to customize the profile page:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 *
 * Default theme implementation for profiles.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - content: Items for the content of the profile.
 *   Use 'content' to print them all, or print a subset such as
 *   'content.title'. Use the following code to exclude the
 *   printing of a given child element:
 *   @code
 *   {{ content|without('title') }}
 *   @endcode
 * - attributes: HTML attributes for the wrapper.
 * - profile: The profile object.
 * - url: The profile URL, if available.
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}
<div{{ attributes.addClass('profile--personnel--teaser') }}>

  <div class="views-row">

    <h3 class="views-teaser-title">
      {{ ??? USERNAME ??? }}
    </h3>

  </div>

</div>
```

How to display the user name that created the profile (the owner of the profile) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get from `getOwner()` method

```
  {{ profile.getOwner().name.value }}
  {{ profile.getOwner().mail.value }}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does not work and displays the following error
 Twig_Error_Syntax: Unexpected ")". in Twig_Lexer->lexExpression() (line 35 of /home/www.domaine.com/public_html/web/themes/contrib/bootstrap_subtheme_front_office/templates/profile--personnel--teaser.html.twig).

Comment: See the updated code. There was an extra `)` in the code.

Comment: Thank you, it works ;-) I do not know this function. Does this work with all entities? How to display the rendered entity of a user's display? How to display the user's photo using an image style?

Comment: Install the devel module and use kint() to debug the variables

Comment: Try this `{{ profile.getOwner().user_picture.entity.url() }}`. It should get image URL

Comment: The code for the url of the image does not work and displays an error. Is it possible to display in the profile, the rendered entity of the user's display (for example teaser) ?

Comment: Are you able to use `kint(profile.getOwner())` there you will get the available methods for that variable. I don't correctly remember how to display URL try `_entity` instead

Comment: Thank you I will test that. But I would like to know if with this code I can display the rendered entity of the display (teaser) of the user in the profile?

Comment: You can get the image **URL** like this`<img src="{{ file_url(profile.uid.entity.user_picture.entity.getFileUri()) }}" >`. To display rendered view mode in twig you can use Twig tweak module or using template preprocess as explained in this answer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/259892/how-to-display-the-rendered-entity-of-the-compact-display-of-the-user-account/259914#259914

Comment: I installed kint and put true in twig debug. I do not know how this module works. The image is well displayed with the code above, but I do not know how to display it with an image style.